# can we reconnect disconnected peripheral using bluetooth without scanning again ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I am making communication between ios device and hardware. If my iOS app and hardware are connected using BLE and connection was established. If hardware is out of range or connection got any issue then iOS app will recheck for available devices automatically and if iOS app got previously paired hardware device then will try to reconnect automatically. What should i do to perform such task. I have gone through many links where they are describing to call `did retrieve connected peripherals` method but by calling this method will it get connected automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can reconnect a disconnected peripheral by queuing up a connect command to that peripheral. It will persist until your app connect to the peripheral, at which point the didConnectPeripheral will be called. No scan necessary.

Comment: Should i call connect command in did disconnect? as soon as hardware comes in range will it automatically get connected? or i have to do anything to make it get connected again

Comment: Yes, I've done so before and your app should reconnect once you've queued up that connect command.

Comment: I am confused whether it will call did retrieve connected peripherals method on its own? where should i queue connect command? In did disconnect? "did retrieve connected peripherals" method is required or not?

Comment: It shouldn't. If you look at the documentation, it says that the callback didRetrieveConnectedPeripherals is returns the result of a retrieveConnectedPeripherals call. If you're not making a retrieveConnectedPeripherals call, didRetrieveConnectedPeripherals won't get called. And yes, you can put it in didDisconnect. This will queue up a connect command and immediately try to reconnect, or if you're not range it will connect when you get back in range.

Comment: should i use "didRetrieveConnectedPeripherals" or "retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:(NSArray *)" which is more feasible to use? and thanks for your help. It solved my doubts.

Comment: didRetrieveConnectedPeripherals and retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices do not do the same thing. You call retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices and then you implement didRetrieveConnectedPeripherals - any code you put there will be run if you successfully retrieve connected peripherals with the list of services you provided.

Comment: "retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:(NSArray *)" and "retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers" method will call delegate method "didRetrieveConnectedPeripherals" only?

Comment: one last question.. i read about "retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices" method is returns a list of the peripherals (containing any of the specified services) currently connected to the system. "currently connected" but what after disconnection? in disconnection i will call "retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices" method and in this call back delegate i will call connect to peripheral but how long connect remain active if hardware remains out of range for long time.